# Permissions to reference files changed in git on push

Tags: server, permissions, git

I have recently set up a Ubuntu server with gitolite and it is mostly working fine. However an issue occurred after I downloaded and setup a web-gui (gitlist) to share my repositories.

I'm sure the problem is that everytime I push up some updates, the file permissions for some reference files in the repository have their file permissions changed and Apache can't access them (and thus, the web-gui won't get access to the repository).

When I installed it, I did the following steps:

1. Created a git user and setup the repositories for this user.
2. Added `www-data` user to the git-group with `usermod -a -G git www-data`
3. Made sure git was the group for the repositories: `sudo chgrp -R git repositories/`
4. Used chmod on the folders to give access for all users in the group: `sudo chmod ug+s repositories/`

As soon as I do a push with git the file permission for 2-3 files are changed (for instance the *'/repository/[name]/refs/head/master'* file) and it is set to `-rw-------`, and only the git-user got access to the file. No other users can read or write here.

I would like that those files would stay with the given permission (for instance `chmod 755`) after I do a git push, so I don't need to update the permissions every time someone does a push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this isa Q&A site, and I found the answer my self after a lot of crawling through google searches and solved this.

The basic problem goes back to a umask that was set, that masked all the files when I did the push - and I had to change this. To do this I did the following:

open the .gitolite.rc file in the root of my repository and set the the variable:

```
$REPO_UMASK = 0022
```

(Set the Umask to the mask you want to have). After this my files were not stripped for the read-permission for the group.